# Prove the gradient of a function is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Assume that $f :B(r,0) $ $\rightarrow $ $\mathbb R^n$ is differentiable and the induced norm $||Df(x)||$ $\leq M$  for every $x \in B(r,0)$.
Let $\mathbf u $ be an arbitrary unit vector and $g(x) = \mathbf u·f(x) = \mathbf u^T f(x)$ be differentiable.
Prove that $|\nabla g(x)| \leq M$ for every $x \in B(r,0)$

I tried to solve it from the definition of differentiability, but I am confused and kind of stuck.

My steps:
since $g(x)$ is differentiable,  $\lim h \rightarrow 0$  $\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)-\nabla g(x)·h}{|h|} =0$
$\lim h \rightarrow 0$  $\frac{\mathbf u^T f(x+h)-\mathbf u^T f(x)-\nabla g(x)·h}{|h|} =0$
since $f(x)$ is also differentiable,

$\lim h \rightarrow 0$  $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)h}{|h|} =0$
I multiply the above equation by $\mathbf u^T$ and get
$\lim h \rightarrow 0$  $\frac{\mathbf u^Tf(x+h)-\mathbf u^Tf(x)-\mathbf u^TDf(x)h}{|h|} =0$
which let me arrive at
$\frac{\nabla g(x)·h}{|h|}= \frac{\mathbf u^TDf(x)h}{|h|}$ which is equavalent to
$\frac{(\nabla g(x))^Th}{|h|} = \frac{\mathbf u^TDf(x)h}{|h|}$
$|\frac{(\nabla g(x))^Th}{|h|}|\leq \mathbf |u^T|M$

But then I am stuck. Am I on the right track?
Can you give me some instruction on what to do next?
Thank you!

Comment: Surely you can conclude that since $|u^T|=1$, then the gradient is bounded, correct?

Comment: @Hossmeister  but then on the left hand side I don't know what to deal with the $\frac{h}{|h|}$ part.  I tried to make it$\geq |gradient(x) |$ but nothing in my head can let me solve that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's compute $Dg(x)$ using the chain rule: $g$ is just the composition $x \stackrel{f}{\longmapsto} f(x) \stackrel{h}{\longmapsto} {\bf u} \cdot f(x)$, and $h$ is linear. Thus $$Dg(x)({\bf v}) = D(h\circ f)(x)({\bf v}) = Dh(f(x))\circ Df(x)({\bf v}) = h(Df(x)({\bf v})) = {\bf u}\cdot Df(x)({\bf v}).$$So $|Dg(x)({\bf v})| = |{\bf u} \cdot Df(x)({\bf v})| \leq \|{\bf u}\| \|Df(x)({\bf v})\|$, by Cauchy-Schwarz. Now, ${\bf u}$ is a unit vector, so we can keep on bounding that using the definition of the operator norm $\|Df(x)\|$: $$|Dg(x)({\bf v})| \leq \|Df(x)\|\|{\bf v}\| \leq M \|{\bf v}\|.$$ Let ${\bf v}$ range over the unit sphere and take the supremum on the left side to get $\|Dg(x)\| \leq M$ as well.